# How to create a property for a List of objects in matlab

Tags: matlab, list, class, properties

I define `Node` class like this in MATLAB:

```
classdef Node
   properties
    X;
    Y;
   end
end
```

I need to define a `HeadNode` class like this:

```
classdef HeadNode 
   properties
     X;
     Y;
     % list<Node> NodeList = new list<Node>(); (C# syntax)
   end
end
```

Also I need to `Add` method for this property like this(C# syntax):

```
HeadNode HeadNode1 = new HeadNode();    
Node Node1 = new Node();
Node1.X = 1;
Node1.Y = 2;
HeadNode1.Nodes.Add(Node1);
```

It would be very helpful if someone could explain How to create a property for a List of objects in matlab and define Add method for this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Matlab does not have data structures like lists, so a general approach would be to store objects in an array. Firstly, inherit both classes from handle:

```
classdef Node < handle
    properties
        x
        y
    end
end
```

Initialize `nodes` property of `HeadNode` to an empty `Node` array using [`empty()`](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/empty.html) method, which is a hidden method of all non-abstract Matlab classes. It is important to perform such initialisation in the constructor and not in the property definition block, otherwise all instances of `HeadNode` would [reference the same location in memory](http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/expressions-in-class-definitions.html#buvarim):

```
classdef HeadNode < handle
    properties
        x
        y
        nodes
    end

    methods
        function obj = HeadNode()
            obj.nodes = Node.empty();
        end
    end
end
```

This way you can e.g. add `node1` to the end of `nodes` array:

```
node1 = Node();
node1.x = 1;
node1.y = 2;
headNode1 = HeadNode();
headNode1.nodes(end+1) = node1;
```

An alternative would be to use java lists, but this way you are limited to storing some primitive types and Java objects, i.e. you would not be able to store a Matlab object in a java list.

Comment: come to think of it ... I misread the question as saying he wanted to create a traditional c-style list (i.e. containing a pointer to the next member). What he's asking is totally doable without the `handle` class.

Comment: That's a very odd structure to have though, if you ask me. I have to wonder if OP misinterpreted / misrepresented the problem he was asked to solve.

Comment: Thank you for answering my question. I've used an array rather than a list.